# Can two separate threads perform a write to a std::atomic<> variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition, stdatomic

I am looking for some clarity on the necessity to lock a variable if std::atomic<> is used on it. Please consider the following code:

```
std::atomic<int> my_integer;

void Thread1()
{
    if (condition1)
    {
       my_integer = 5;
    }
   
    if (my_integer == 7)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}

void Thread2()
{
    if (condition2)
    {
        my_integer = 7;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to use a mutex around the writes and reads to my_integer? Or would the atomic variable provide adequate thread safe protection? Is there a possibility of any race condition occurring here? If so, what would that race condition be? Thanks in advance for any insight!

I was thinking that std::atomic should protect the assignment to my_integer, so that whenever it is read, it is always the most up-to-date version of the variable.

Comment: It's not a race condtition, but a write-after-write (WAW) data hazard. You cannot be sure which thread was run later, so you don't known if `my_integer` is `5` or `7`. But adding a mutex won't help, the problem is with the design that lets two threads write to the same variable without anything to synchronise them.

Comment: The code is "safe" in that it is free of undefined behavior, but it also doesn't really make sense.  The function `doSomething()` may either be called or not on any given run, and it's unclear why you would want that uncertainty.  Start by defining clearly what you *want* the code to do, then you can ask a more sensible question about whether your code actually achieves that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! The idea I was trying to get across is Thread1 does not care what the value is of my_integer, just that is has the most up-to-date version of that based on the synchronized atomic operations. @Yksisarvinen I believe std::atomic would synchronize the writes to my_integer, would it not?

Comment: @EmbeddedDOOD2 As I said, there is no race condition - no fear that two threads would try to write to the same memory location at the same time. Data hazards are different level of abstraction - assuming no race conditions, can you tell what is the value at memory address P at any given moment in time when something reads from P? If not, that's a data hazard. And you shouldn't simply "not care, as long it's the most updated one" - per C++ standard that's Undefined Behaviour. All access to shared data must be synchronised, there can't be a situation where you can't predict what is there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: That's not correct, there is no UB here.  Access to *non-atomic* shared data must be synchronized.  But it is perfectly fine to not be able to predict the value of an atomic object.  The code here has defined behavior - it will either call `doSomething()` or not call it, and it is *unspecified* which will be the case, but it will not behave unpredictably otherwise.  If it were truly UB, it could also legally print out insulting messages about your mother - but the code here must not do any such thing.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: The code is very likely not *useful*, and may be buggy in that it may not be doing what the author wants, but its behavior in terms of the C++ standard is well defined.

Comment: Trying to think in terms of "most up-to-date" is usually not the right way to think.  The C++ memory model doesn't work in those terms - generally, it tries to avoid the very idea that threads should be synchronized with respect to *time*.  Rather, you think in terms of which loads and stores may or may not be guaranteed to observe one another.  Atomics are a means to an end, so step back from this isolated snippet and look at the larger program you are trying to write.  What is your actual goal for how it should behave?

Comment: @NateEldredge I disagree. Per [intro.races#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-4), all modifications of an object must have a total ordering. Two unsequenced writes before a sequenced read do not meet that condition.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: They *do* have a total order.  On any given run of the program, either the store of 5 precedes the store of 7, or vice versa.  But it could be different from one run to the next, and we are not directly informed as to which one it is.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen:  In the former case, the load may return either 5 or 7 - it is unspecified which - but it must not return any other value.  (See for instance [p14](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-14): "The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, is the value stored by some **unspecified** side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.") In the latter case, it must return 5.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Being able to make unsequenced reads and writes is the entire point of an atomic object.  The memory ordering rules don't necessarily let you deduce with certainty the value that any given atomic load will return, but they do let you deduce the *set* of possible values, and if your program logic can deal with all of them, you are fine.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: As a very basic example, think of an atomic object used to implement a spinlock mutex: when you go to lock it, you don't know in advance whether you will get the value 0 (the lock is available) or 1 (it is taken).  But you handle both alternatives: if 1, you spin and retry; if 0, you take the lock and proceed into the critical section.

Comment: @NateEldredge I give up, I can't understand this bit of standard. I guess you are right, but I can't verify that reading it myself.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Terminology note: It's not a WAW *hazard* like in CPU architecture. 
 The term "hazard" implies there is one correct order that we need to get as the final result, like if doing out-of-order exec on `mov eax, [rdi]` / `push rax` / `mov eax, 123` / ... while preserving the illusion of running instructions one at a time in program order from a single thread of execution.  In that case the final value of RAX must be 123, if you don't run any more instructions that write RAX.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: But with two threads, there's no pre-defined order; whichever write gets MESI ownership second becomes the second in the modification order for that location, overwriting the value of the other write.  The modification order is "discovered" by the machine in cases where no synchronization forced one write to happen-before the other.  (ISO C++ of course doesn't talk about MESI; that's an implementation detail for the C++ coherency requirements.)